# split strings in array and convert to map

Tags: scala

I am reading a file composed of lines in the format `a=b`.
Using `Source.fromFile("file").getLines` I get an `Iterator[String]`. I figure I need to split the strings into tuples and then form the map from the tuples - that is easy. I am not being able to go from the `Iterator[String]` to an `Iterator[(String,String)]`.

How can I do this? I am a beginner to scala and not experienced with functional programming, so I am receptive to alternatives :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by splitting the string and then creating the tuples from the first and second elements using `Iterator.map`:

```
val strings = List("a=b", "c=d", "e=f").iterator
val result: Iterator[(String, String)] = strings.map { s =>
  val split = s.split("=")
  (split(0), split(1))
}
```

If you don't mind the extra iteration and intermediate collection you can make this a little prettier:

```
val result: Iterator[(String, String)] =
  strings
   .map(_.split("="))
   .map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the values returned by an Iterator using the `map` method:

`def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Iterator[B]`

Comment: I am so very sorry but do not understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
Source.fromFile("file").getLines.map(_.split("=").map( x => (x.head,x.tail) ) )
```

You might want to wrap this into `Try`.

Comment: Maybe also use `mkString("=")` on the tail, so you are sure you have (String,String), no matter how many splits there were.

Answer (score 0):

This is my try:

```
 val strings = List("a=b", "c=d", "e=f")
 val map = strings.map(_.split("=")).map { case Array(f1,f2) => (f1,f2) }
```